# No suitable driver found for jdbc://localhost

Tags: mysql, servlets, jdbc, jetty

I have a simple servlet deployed on a Jetty 9 server on Ubuntu 14.04. It was working fine till yesterday. But after a system crash, i had problems with MySQL server, so had to make configuration changes to the mysql server to make it work i.e. added the line 
`socket = /tmp/mysql.sock` under sections `[mysqld]` and `[client]` in `my.cnf`

But now the servlet is not working. It gives me the below error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/slappdb
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at slappserver.RegisterServlet.doGet(RegisterServlet.java:74)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have made no changes to the servlet code at all :

```
final String DB_URL = DatabaseParameters.SlappDbURL;
final String USER = DatabaseParameters.DbServer_Username;
final String PASSWORD = DatabaseParameters.DbServer_Password;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASSWORD);
```

The driver is at the same place as before : `/home/faizal/DEV/jre1.7.0_55/lib/ext/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar`, which is included in the build path of the project.

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Put the jar in IDE's project lib folder. Because, on build, it should go into war file.

Comment: That should not make any difference, as the JRE lib also gets included in the WAR.

Comment: What is your IDE setting for runtime class path reference.

Comment: My IDE shows ECLIPSE_HOME(/home/faizal/DEV/eclipse) in classpath variable. But my project does have the JRE system library(where the driver is located) under Java Build Path. Anyway it is working now magically. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something seemed to have got corrupted in my project because of the crash. It is working now after i added the line `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` in the servlet. But this line is actually not required since i am using a JDBC 4 driver.

Interestingly, now even if i remove this line, it works. So, i am still not sure what was the problem, but atleast it's working as before without any change in code.